# Parse server account key

Tags: parse-server

Installed Parse Server on Digital Ocean, and have been trying to use the CLI to manage cloud code.  I've hit a wall, since the CLI tool will not move forward without an account key on Parse.com (which no longer offers account keys).  For example, if I type in "parse new", I get this:

```
We've changed the way the CLI works.  To save time logging in, you should create an account key.  Type "parse configure accountkey" to create a new account key.  Read more at: https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#command-line-account-keys
```

If you actually do that, it responds:

```
Input your account key or press ENTER to generate a new one.  NOTE: on pressing ENTER we'll try to open the url: "https://www.parse.com/account/keys" in the default browser:
```

This leads to a login page.  Since I don't have an account on Parse.com (nor should it be necessary for Parse Server), I'm stuck.  If I click on the "I don't have an account" link, it just takes me to the front page.

I find it hard to believe that there's no way to manage/create cloud code on Parse Server.  But, it is sure looking that way.  Is this just a failure to update the CLI or am I missing something obvious.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Parse cli is not meant to be used with parse server. At least not currently. Parse server is simply a node module which means that you will have to handle deployment etc yourself. There are many tools that will handle everything that the parse cli did, and much more, from the nodejs community however.

You said that you used digital ocean. You might want to consider heroku, aws or google cloud. Heroku for example has the heroku cli with many of the same features as the parse cli which might save you some time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use parse cli on parse-server. Parse-server and parse.com environment are both different , parse-server is just the node module so deployment can be automated using other tools.
I am using forever to restart my parse-server automatically when a file changes. So you can just copy/paste your files using filezilla and that's it.